# Disable CICD build from triggering automatically yet keep it open for manual trigger

Tags: build, triggers, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

I have 2 CICD pipeline (Build A & Build B) based on the branch X. However I would like to make sure only Build A is triggered every time there is a pull request.

Yes, I can disable the pipeline from triggering changing the settings like this, however if I do that I cant manually trigger the build.

[image]

Is there a way to disable automatic trigger yet keep the option of manually triggering open?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Thanks... I actually marked the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have 2 CICD pipeline (Build A & Build B) based on the branch X

Agree with Krzysztof Madej.

If you create pull request and the build B is automatically triggered. We could set `pr: none` or check the [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) `Build Validation`

if PR is completed and the Build B is automatically triggered, we could set `trigger: none` to disable the [CI Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#push-trigger).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you should set `pr: none`. Please check PR triggers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers)

In the same way you can control [CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)